# How can I delete nodes when an arbitrary date has past?

Tags: rules, datetime

I have a situation where future events will be posted to the website in question. These future events are a content type with a date field using the date module.

I wish to automatically delete these events once their date has past. I'm assuming that rules should do this but I have searched and I am struggling to find a way to do this.

Comment: Is it important to delete or would un publishing be ok. If so check the 'scheduler' module.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the hook_cron to solve your problem

```
function mymodule_cron(){
  _mymodule_delete_nodes();
}

function _mymodule_delete_nodes(){
  //select all nodes from type X where date expired
  //node_delete($nid);
}
```

See [hook_cron](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_cron/7) for further information